# Rust. Чем отличаются типы? u32 & i32?

Tags: rust, типы

Я тут читал раст бук, и не могу понять в чем же отличаются `i32` и `u32`.

Дайте обширный ответ на эту тему, желательно своими словами, а не ссылкой на главу на это.

Спасибо

Comment: i32 могут быть отрицательными, u32 не могут

Comment: В растбуке все же блин разжевано. И знаковый и беззнаковый, и какие значения могут хранить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип данных i32 и u32 отличаются друг от друга в первую очередь знаковостью.

i32 представляет собой 32-битное целое число со знаком, то есть может хранить как положительные, так и отрицательные значения. Например, i32 может хранить значения от -2,147,483,648 до 2,147,483,647.

С другой стороны, u32 представляет собой 32-битное целое число без знака. Таким образом, u32 может хранить только положительные значения. Максимальное значение, которое может хранить u32, составляет 4,294,967,295.

Используя i32, вы можете работать с отрицательными значениями, а с u32 - только с положительными. В зависимости от необходимости выбирайте между этими двумя типами данных в Rust

Comment: Какой лучше всего использовать?

Comment: @Neisven, "лучше" тут не подходит. Обычно задача диктует выбор "знаковости" типа. Но если вы только начинаете знакомиться с задачей, то первый выбор `i32`.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо. Я обычно не знаком сильно с програмированием. Так что спасибо за информацию!